# How to resolve a null binding on a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

**Overview:**
I've set a binding on a ComoboBox to a List property. But when I run the application there is no data populated in the combo box.

**Debug steps:**

- I checked the output window for binding errors which tells me that the data source might be null.
- I then set a breakpoint on the setter of the QueryList property. This shows that the list count is 0. It seems the call to init executes after the setter is called on the property.

My thoughts are that the list is being initialized after the setter is called. Meaning that the binding will be null at that stage the binding is called on the combo box.

**Question:**

How can I call the Init method for my list prior to the QueryList setter being called?

**Code snippet:**

Code behind -

```
    //The binding property for the combo box
    private List<string> _queryList;
    public List<string> QueryList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._queryList;
        }
        set
        {
            this._queryList = value;
        }

    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Establish the Login control
        Ctrl = new CrmLogin();
        QueryList = new List<string>();
        InitQueryList();
    }

    //Call to init the list data
    private void InitQueryList()
    {
        _queryList.Add("Query queues with unapproved email routers");
        _queryList.Add("Query queues with emails in pending send status");
    }
```

Combobox binding setup -

```
 <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryList}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="queryComboBox" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="Select a query"/>
```

Comment: have you tried calling InitializeComponent() at the end of the constructor?

Comment: try using ObservableCollection instead of List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to set your DataContext  :

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
         this.DataContext = this;
        // Establish the Login control
        Ctrl = new CrmLogin();
        QueryList = new List<string>();
        InitQueryList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // Establish the Login control
    QueryList = new List<string>();
    InitQueryList();
    InitializeComponent();
    Ctrl = new CrmLogin();
}
```

Comment: I tried moving the InitializeComponent(); call in that order. But the binding is still blank on the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are using Code behind method MVC then you would need to update the datasource using

```
comboBox1.DataSource = QueryList;
```

Else if you are using the standard MVVM format then you would need to use

> INotifyPropertyChanged

Else You will need to use

> ObservableCollection

This happens because on initialization null value of your _querylist gets binded initially. Now when your querylist gets updated this doesnt get reflected in your view as View doesnt get any notification or event stating that a change has been made to the viewmodel(your binded item)